# want to schedule multiple queries with multiple time frequencies

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled

want to schedule multiple queries with multiple time frequencies

query1: want to schedule for every 1 hours

query2: want to schedule for every 6 hours

query3: want to schedule for every 12 hours

query4: want to schedule for every 24 hours

how to do it??

Comment: Do you want the cron expression or you want to do it using one class only

Comment: What are you exactly asking ? How to schedule ? how to for 4 queries ? How to express a schedule ?  Updating your question (by edit) with the specific problem you have, will lead much faster to the answer you seek.

Comment: I want to schedule 4 queries with different time frequency and check condition whether the queries is executed it must not execute 2nd time in same time frequeny

Comment: It feels like a great question, but I still miss some info: do you want to run the same query? what do you want to do with the resutls? what do you mean : not execute 2nd time in same time frequency? please elaborate more in the Q

Comment: k for example i am having 4 different queries with different time lines/frequencies for example i am a having a query which executes for every 1 hour if the query is executed then my apex must check whether it is executed or not and then continue for the other query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing too many details about what you mean by 'Scheduling queries', I would assume you want to do something with the records that are returned by the queries.  You would want to write a class that implements the Schedulable Interface.

The example below if for your query 1 scenario

```
global class SchedJob implements Schedulable{

    public static String schedule = '0 00 * * * ?';  //Runs every hour 

    global static String scheduleMyJob() {
         SchedJob SJ = new SchedJob(); 
         return System.schedule('Your Job Name', schedule, SJ);
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
         //you would want to use your query here
         list<your_record__c> records = [Select ID From your_Record__c Where....];

         //Your logic here          
    }
}
```

Then for the other queries, all you really need to do is change the chron string to match the interval, and adjust your query

**For you other queries**

```
String schedule = '0 0 0,6,12,18 ? * *';  //Every 6 hours (at set times)

String schedule = '0 0 0,12 ? * *';  //Every 12 hours (at set times)

String schedule = '0 00 00 * * ?';  //Every 24 hours (run each day at midnight)
```

***Then, to actually schedule your job, just use the scheduler method in the class in an Apex anonymous window in the dev console, Eclipse, MavensMate, etc.***

```
SchedJob.scheduleMyJob();
```